# it works even if width is set to 0

Tags: html, css

This may seem like a strange question.
In this simple example I have set width: 0 for selector h3. If I use IE 9 and use F12 development tools I can see that the width is actually 0 but the text that is within the h3 is displayed even though and is definately longer then 0. Can somebody explain how the result can be like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Chapter 5: Indestructible Boxes</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
           body 
           {
              font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
              font-size: small;
            }

            h3
            {
               background :blue;
               width:0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h3>Gifts and Special Offers v Gifts and Special Offers Gifts and Special 
        Offers</h3>
    </body>
 </html>
```

//tony

Comment: what are you doing exactly? making text of `h3` hidden?

Comment: There are couple of ways to achieve this, change `display` of `<h3>` to `none`, set `font-size` to `0`, set `overflow` to `hidden` while you've set it's dimension to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: hidden;`:

```
h3
{
   background :blue;
   width:0px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally width is not a valid attribute for < h3>  tag.
To hide it, use:

```
h3
{
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to  making text of h3 hidden you can use

```
 h3
        {
           background :blue;
           width:0px;

          overflow:hidden
        }
```

or

```
     h3
            {
               background :blue;
               width:0px;
               display:none
        }
```

Comment: This is only just for test and experimenting. I only want to know how can the text being displayed when I have set the width:0. As I sais I don't want to accomplish anything I just experimenting trying to learn how CSS works.